# Symfony - easyadmin hide action buttons

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I want to remove a delete option button in my user list view.

I tried:

```
- label: 'Users'
          icon: 'users'
          children:
            - { label: 'Users', icon: 'list', entity: 'User', disabled_actions: ['delete']}
```

Comment: I think you misplaced the `disabled_actions` property. Can you show the rest of the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chapter 7 you will find exemples how to diable actions : https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/actions-configuration.html

If you want more help, show the rest of your configuration.

Comment: thats it https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/actions-configuration.html#disable-actions-for-some-or-all-entities

Comment: Answers should have supporting details along with the link. Link-only answers are not welcome on Stack Overflow, if these details are missing. Also, this link is broken.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I updated the link. As for the details, I pointed out where to find the configuration examples.
I think, adding more details based on a documentation may be not a good practice. Things may change as you can notice with the link.